# Assembly program

Tags: assembly

I want to make a program in Assembly that will read a string from keyboard then convert every letter throughout another table and then store it in a table at [201]. At [200] I have a char counter of my string. Here is what I have done:

```
mov [0300h],88h        ;thats the table that I want to convert to.(only 3 digits)

mov [0301h],83h

mov [0302h],0CEh


mov ah,01h                     ;insert string 
int 81h                   


mov di,01h                 

start: 
mov al,[di]  
cmp al,00h          ;not
    sure about that. last char of string
    should be /0.

je end                  
mov [0200h],di    ;char counter.    
inc di

mov bx,0300h      
sub al,041h
    ;convert char 
xlat 
mov [di+01ffh],al
    ;store converted char to 201...

loop start 

end:

**int 81h**
;reads chars until <cr> from keyboard.Starting  address of input data buffer             ES:DI+1
```

For some reason DI takes value 0900 at the end of my programm. Any idea why it doesn't work, or any idea that I can make it by any other way? thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov al,[di]
```

Shouldn't you add an offset to your input buffer here?

Comment: can you give an example plz? thnx

Comment: Your code assumes that your input buffer starts at ds:[1]. Is that really the case?

Answer (score 0):

It's soo broken.. take a look at this as exemple (it considers that fn 1 of int81 reads a char. no idea of the actual interface) :

```
some_table: db 88h, 83h, CEh
result:     db ??(128) // can't recall the syntax

push ds
pop  es
lea bx, some_table
lea di, result // for stosb to work

start: 
mov ah,01h                     ;//insert string 
int 81h                   
cmp al, 0Ah  // enter in linux (or it's 0Dh?)
je end                  
sub al, 'A' // what do you mean by "convert to char"? it's already a char. and what happens if it's larger than 'C'?
xlat 
stosb 
jmp start 
end:
```

Comment: hmmm. i just don't know if bgc8088 can support this kind of tables.i want to convert chars, i have made a circuit that will display "converted" chars. my A will be the 88h instead of 41h and so on.

Comment: int 81 doesn't take one char. it reads chars until <CR> from keyboard "enter in bgc8088"

Comment: so i don't know if i can use stosb.